# Subscrever uma session php

Tags: php, session

Quando o usuário acessar a pagina de detalhes do imóvel no meu site, eu preciso armazenar o e-mail do corretor em uma session, e quando ele enviar o formulário de proposta, o e-mail do corretor é enviado para o arquivo responsável pelo disparo de e-mail em input hidden, eu recupero o e-mail dele no arquivo email.php e é enviado a proposta direto para ele através do phpmailer.

Ex: Acessando o imóvel 3174, vou armazenar o email do corretor x responsável por esse imóvel, se acessar outro imóvel destrói a sessão anterior e cria uma nova com o e-mail do corretor do imóvel atual.

```
//Aqui eu crio a session['corretor']
if(!isset($_SESSION['corretor'])){
    echo $_SESSION['corretor']=$results['email'];
}
```

Como faço para que toda vez que seja acessado um imóvel diferente, seja destruído a sessão atual e criado uma nova armazenando o e-mail do corretor responsável pelo imóvel?

Comment: toda vez que você setar a sessão, ele já irá resetar a sessão anterior. Mas você pode destruir uma sessão apenas assim: `unset($_SESSION['corretor'])`.

Comment: @IvanFerrer, muito obrigado pela colaboração, já foi solucionado. Qlqer coisa fico a disposição.

Answer (score 3):

Na página do imóvel onde você seta o valor da SESSION coloque na linha acima:

```
unset($_SESSION['corretor']);
```

Isso destruirá a sessão criada, porém não é necessário pois sempre que você passa um novo valor para essa SESSION ele substituirá o valor antigo.

OBS: Retire o SESSION de dentro da validação `if(!isset($_SESSION['corretor'])){}` porque se não você só vai conseguir setar da primeira vez, que é quando ele ainda não existe.

Comment: é isso cara não precisava daquela validação. Somente setando a sessão já era, vai resetando conforme eu mudar de imóvel. Vlw! Obrigado!